# Projection with single child object

Tags: mongodb, projection

Say I have something like:

```
{ "_id" : 1, "semester" : 1, "grades" : { student1: 70, student2: 85 }}
{ "_id" : 1, "semester" : 1, "grades" : { student1: 55, student2: 24 }}
```

I want to do a `find()` and in my projection I just want `student2`, which is a child object/attribute of `grades`

My naive approach:

`db.streets.find({dowhatever}, {_id:1, grades.student2: 1})`

Didn't work so then I looked into http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/ and I thought maybe `$slice` would be what I want, but doesn't seem to be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can [access fields inside an embedded document using the dot notation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/project-fields-from-query-results/#return-specific-fields-in-embedded-documents). Don't forget to quote the field name though.

```
> db.collection.find()
{ "_id" : 1, "semester" : 1, "grades" : { "student1" : 70, "student2" : 85 } }
{ "_id" : 2, "semester" : 2, "grades" : { "student1" : 55, "student2" : 24 } }

> db.collection.find({_id: 2}, { "grades.student2": 1})
{ "_id" : 2, "grades" : { "student2" : 24 } }
```

Please note that `_id` is implicitly projected. You don't have to specify it, unless you want to remove it (`_id: 0`).

Comment: The issue is that I wasn't quoting the field name